# Qt lupdate in .pro file issue

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-linguist

I had to mark some of the .xml files for internationalization. I do not use lupdate manually from cmd, instead I put it in the project's .pro file like:

```
lupdate_only{
 SOURCES += $$EXTRA_XML
}
```

The above code works just fine, but as you noticed I had to put the xml files in SOURCES. As a consequence the .xml files appear in the *Sources* virtual folder from the left Projects' perspective window, just next to the .cpp files. I find this solution a bit nasty and confusing.

```
- Project
- - Headers
- - Sources
- - - main.cpp
- - - some.xml //not wanted here
```

Is there a way to use lupdate, in .pro, on different files such that those files won't appear in the Sources folder? Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I use Qt Creator 4.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, however I think it's a Qt Creator bug. I just moved the lupdate statement with its contents into a .pri file and now the xml files do not appear under the Sources virtual folder. (the .pri file is included in .pro)

Comment: Glad you found an acceptable solution, I hadn't thought about using a .pri

Answer (score 1):

```
lupdate_only {
    SOURCES += $$EXTRA_XML
}
```

With this conditional statement, lupdate tool sees the .qml files but qmake will ignore it.

Comment: The lupdate_only seems to be a conditional statement for the compiler but I think the problem is with the Qt Creator which parses the .pro files and interprets the SOURCES variable

Comment: In that case, the only other possible solution I can think of, is that you make a separate .pro file, containing just the lupdate_only { ... } and the xml files. You will then need to run lupdate from the command line yourself, while Qt Creator works with the other .pro file containing all the C++ headers and sources.

Comment: It's almost the same thing as running the lupdate from cmd, however your response gave me the idea to move lupdate into the .pri file and not it works as desired, so thank you